# StarDog Login error

Tags: javascript, stardog

i'm trying to login into Stardog tool with 
username : admin
password : admin

sounds straightforward but i do get a login error saying [Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:5820/scripts/06942fff.main.js :: .send :: line 3" data: no '

Is there a point of concept i've overlooked to solve this issue? Any suggestion for this issue would be helpful.

[image]